# Заполнение связных таблиц один-ко-многим

Tags: mysql

Попробую еще раз.

Есть две связанные таблицы. Таблица с заказами (Order), и таблица с составом заказов (OrderList).
Связанны поля `Order.ID и OrderList.order_ID`

Заполняю первую таблицу обычным INSERT'ом, а вот как заполнить вторую таблицу, если к примеру у меня несколько товаров? Нужно как-то получить ID из главной таблицы который является автоинкрементом.

Заполнять вторую таблицу планирую в цикле, поэтому `LAST_INSERT_ID();`, не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам этот вопрос

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`users_ID`, `date`) VALUES (2, 2018-02-02)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id;
INSERT INTO `orders_list` (`orders_ID`,`products_ID`,`amount`) VALUES(@last_id,4,55)
```